# Shifting .NET MAUI Flyout to the Right with FlowDirection?

Tags: xaml, maui, right-to-left, .net-maui.shell

How can I shift the .NET MAUI Flyout to the Right (e.g. with `FlowDirection`) using Shell?

I am currently developing an application using .NET MAUI and am facing an issue with the Flyout menu (Sidebar). I am aiming for a right-to-left layout to better cater to right-to-left languages.

So far, I attempted to use `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"` attribute within the Shell as follows:

```xml
<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       x:Class="MyApp.AppShell"
       FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
```

Although this successfully reversed my content direction, it did not affect the Flyout menu which still slides from the left. I am trying to make the Flyout emerge from the right instead.

Is there a way to accomplish this in .NET MAUI ?

Comment: Although I think that I understand your question, it would be helpful to see an image of what you're trying to accomplish. I don't think that moving the entire Flyout menu to the right side of the screen is supported out-of-the-box in .NET MAUI.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I get that .NET MAUI might not natively support shifting the Shell's Flyout to the right. My app targets right-to-left languages and needs the Flyout to emerge from the right, not the left.

It should visually mirror the default Flyout, just emerging from the right. Think of the usual Flyout, simply reflected on the y-axis.

If .NET MAUI doesn't have this feature built-in, could you offer an alternative approach or tailored solution? Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Comment: You might be able to change the position and animation of the Flyout button and menu using [custom handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize), but this will take some research as well as trial-and-error. You could also add this as a feature request in the MAUI GitHub repository, however it's not guaranteed to be implemented anytime soon by the MAUI team.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Following your advice, I created a discussion on the .NET MAUI GitHub repository for additional guidance. The discussion can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/15202

Any additional ideas or contributions to the discussion on GitHub would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I notice you have raised an issue on Github: [How to switch .NET MAUI Flyout of Shell to the right with FlowDirection?](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15221). You could follow this thread.